# Una funcion ignora el limite establecido en un If-Else

Tags: java, netbeans

Puede que suene algo confuso, pero trataré de explicarme lo mejor posible.

Tengo un proyecto en el que tengo que dibujar, al menos, 4 figuras, de las cuales debo poder moverlas en una zona determinada, evitando que sobrelape los botones/resto del programa. Estoy utilizando un `if` para determinar si los `eje X/eje Y` están dentro de la zona disponible (posiblemente no es la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero no he encontrado cómo limitar el movimiento de la figura).

Actualización 2:
Limitador del eje X minimo (izquierda):

```
    private String AxisXMin(){
    Object itemSelec = cmbFigura.getSelectedItem();
    if (itemSelec.equals("Cuadrado")){
        if(showAxisX()>15)return "valido";
    } else if (itemSelec.equals("Circulo")) {
        if(showAxisX()>15)return "valido";
    } else if (itemSelec.equals("Rectangulo")) {
        if(showAxisX()>15)return "valido";
    } else if (itemSelec.equals("Ovalo")) {
        if(showAxisX()>15)return "valido";
    }
    return "null";
    }
```

Boton:

```
    private void btnIzquierdaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (AxisXMin().equals("valido")){
        izquierda();
        clickSD();
    }else{derecha();clickNV();}
    ctrlKey();
    }
```

**ctrlKey no es parte de las funciones de mover la figura**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que separar las condiciones que se deben cumplir para mover las figuras hacia arriba de las que se deben cumplir para poder moverlas hacia abajo, y lo mismo para izquierda/derecha. Sino, cuando `y` vale 65, `limitadorAxisY()` devuelve "valido", `arriba()` le resta uno `y = 64` y a partir de ahí no se va a volver a cumplir ninguna condición.
Es decir, cuando llames al método `arriba()` tenés que comprobar sólo que `y` sea mayor que 64, y cuando llames al método `abajo()` que sea menor que 276.

Comment: Habría que revisar las funciones derecha, izquierda y ctrlKey.

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregue.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo con la explicación de N.N, pero creo que la solución más fácil sería cambiar los valores de los lìmites. Te quedaría asi:

```
private String limitadorAxisY(){
    Object itemSelec = cmbFigura.getSelectedItem();
    if (itemSelec.equals("Cuadrado")){
        if((cu.getY()>65)&&(cu.getY()<275))return "valido";
    } else if (itemSelec.equals("Circulo")) {
        if((ci.getY()>65)&&(ci.getY()<323))return "valido";
    } else if (itemSelec.equals("Rectangulo")) {
        if((re.getY()>65)&&(re.getY()<374))return "valido";
    } else if (itemSelec.equals("Ovalo")) {
        if((ov.getY()>65)&&(ov.getY()<374))return "valido";
    }
    return "null";
}
```

Ps: no se si te diste cuenta pero en tu última condicion esta `ov.getX()` en vez de `ov.getY()`